# Python Heroku app has 0 web dynos despite Procfile

Tags: python, heroku

I created a Heroku app from an existing Python (Pyramid) project. All the dependencies appear to install correctly. I created a `Procfile` that specifies a web dyno, and it runs fine locally with foreman. However, when I deploy, no web dynos launch. This is verified in the logs. The Heroku dashboard also lists no dynos at all for this app.

What might I be doing wrong?

*Clarifications:*

Scaling web dynos fails this way:

```
$ heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling web dynos... failed
 !    Resource not found
```

Here is my `Procfile`:

```
web: pserve production.ini
```

Comment: have you tried scaling it manually with:
`$ heroku ps:scale web=1` ?

Comment: Yes, it fails with a "Resource not found" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered my own question after stepping through tutorials more carefully.

It turns out the problem was just with how I had my `virtualenv` and git repository configured. The `Procfile` was fine, but it was not in the root of the repository...so Heroku was unable to find it. I moved the `Procfile` up into the root of the repository, and voila—works fine!

Answer (score 3):

@agconti is correct, and deserves the points.

Just to explain: `Procfile` only specifies the "types" of dynos your app has, not how many of each you need. You need to scale up by either running `heroku ps:scale web=1` to by doing it from the dashboard.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be my problem. I did try scaling it up, and that failed with an error. I now think it's more likely a problem with the `Procfile` itself. Will try experimenting more with that...

Comment: @Nitzan  Thanks for offering to share the rep (+1) !